# Tricky summation of the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

What does $$-50^2-2\cdot (49)^2-3\cdot(48)^2-.....-0\cdot0^2+1^2(51)+2^2(52)+...(50)^2100$$equal? I don't know what to do. Also I couldn't find any symmetry here so I am stuck over this problem. Thanks!

Comment: $50^2(2*50-1) + 49^2(2*49-1) + ... + 1^2(2*1-1)$.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $50\cdot 0^2$ for the last term in the negative series?

Comment: No its $-1.50^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$−50^2−2⋅(49)^2−3⋅(48)^2−.....−0⋅0^2+1^2(51)+2^2(52)+...(50)^2100$
=$50^2(2∗50−1)+49^2(2∗49−1)+...+1^2(2∗1−1)$
=$2(50^3+49^3+...+1^3)-(50^2+49^2+...+1^2)$
=$2(\frac{50∗51}{2})^2-(\frac{1}{6}*50*51*101)$
=3208325
You are good to go!

Comment: Oops I made a mistake and it is okay now.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the following:

$$-50^2+(50)^2.100=50^2(100-1)=50^2(2.50-1)$$
$$-2.49^2+(49)^2.99=49^2(99-2)=49^2(2.49-1)$$

and so on we have

$$-50.1^2+1^2.51=1^2(51-50)=1^2(2.1-1)$$

Hence the given series = $1^2(2.1-1)+2^2(2.2-1)....+49^2(2.49-1)+50^2(2.50-1)$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{50} 2.n^3-n^2=2\sum_{n=1}^{50}n^3-\sum_{n=1}^{50}n^2$$
$$=2\Big(\frac{50(50+1)}{2}\Big)^2-\frac{50(50+1)(2.50+1)}{6}$$
$$=2 \times 1625625-42925=3208325$$